# Startup intramfs error loading Ubuntu 22.04.01

Tags: boot

Since the last Ubuntu update, I am now required to run a 'manual fsck' on /dev/sda8 every time I try to boot into Ubuntu.
I am sometimes required to run this 'manual fsck' more than once to get Ubuntu to start.
Often my pc (HP 360 Convertible) will then freeze (no mouse or keyboard action works) requiring me to long-press the power button and re-start.

Comment: It seems that your disk is failing.

Comment: @Pilot6:  Thanks for the heads-up Pilot6 - I am now looking for a replacement disk drive - I have done a full backup of the current disk drive in anticipation of a catestrophic disk failure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the heads-up Pilot6 - I am now looking for a replacement disk drive - I have done a full backup of the current disk drive in anticipation of a catestrophic disk failure.

**Please CLOSE this question.**